Invariants of nested loops
I have to fully annote the following program and I currently have a hard time with finding the invariants for the loops:
{ 0 <= n }
r := 0;
x := 0;
do[false] // find invariant for the outer loop
  x < n ->
    y := 0;
    do[false] // find invariant for the inner loop
      y < n -> 
        r := r + 1;
        y := y + 1
    od;
    { y = n } // add inner loop invariant here
    x := x + 1 
od
{ r = n * n }

Any suggestions on how to tackle the problem?
